# Cannot describe a Hive table created using avro serde

Tags: hadoop, hive, avro, describe

I have created a Hive table with Avro serde. Below is the code that I have copied from a website to create my table.

```
create table NEW_TABLE
     row format serde 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe'
     stored as inputformat 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat'
     outputformat 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat'
     tblproperties ('avro.schema.literal'='{
        "name": "my_record",
        "type": "record",
        "fields": [
           {"name":"boolean1", "type":"boolean"},
           {"name":"int1", "type":"int"},
           {"name":"long1", "type":"long"},
           {"name":"float1", "type":"float"},
           {"name":"double1", "type":"double"},
           {"name":"string1", "type":"string"},
           {"name": "nullable_int", "type": ["int", "null"]]}');
```

When I issued the command to describe the table I received the below error:

```
hive> describe new_table;
OK
error_error_error_error_error_error_error       string                  from deserializer
cannot_determine_schema string                  from deserializer
check                   string                  from deserializer
schema                  string                  from deserializer
url                     string                  from deserializer
and                     string                  from deserializer
literal                 string                  from deserializer
Time taken: 0.15 seconds, Fetched: 7 row(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

I later discovered that the fields in the avro schema were separated by tab. I copied the code in notepad and removed the tabs and re run the command. It worked!!!

Comment: I had a trailing comma on my list of schema properties